# How to say choices in Japanese?

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

How to say "choices" that describes choices given in test questions?

Answer (score 4):

You can say [[選択肢]{せんたくし}](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E8%82%A2+%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89).

> 例: ４つの選択肢の中から正しい答えを選びなさい。
>   (Choose the right answer from the four options.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, 選択 (せんたく) is used.